# Site fails to load with aurelia-bundler -- blank page, no errors

Tags: systemjs, aurelia

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing, but for the life of me I cannot get the aurelia bundler to work.

When I run `gulp serve-export`, using the bundles, I get a blank page and no errors. The `System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper')` promise never returns.

**[config.js gist](https://gist.github.com/htxryan/678ff862dd96d4e37700d8aed124133a)**

**Bundles**

```
module.exports = {
  "bundles": {
    "dist/app-build": {
      "includes": [
        "[**/*.js]",
        "**/*.html!text",
        "**/*.css!text",
        "**/*.json!text"
      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": true,
        "rev": false
      }
    },
    "dist/aurelia": {
      "includes": [
        "aurelia-framework",
        "aurelia-bootstrapper",
        "aurelia-fetch-client",
        "aurelia-router",
        "aurelia-animator-css",
        "aurelia-templating-binding",
        "aurelia-polyfills",
        "aurelia-templating-resources",
        "aurelia-templating-router",
        "aurelia-loader-default",
        "aurelia-history-browser",
        "aurelia-logging-console",
        "bootstrap",
        "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!text",
        "fetch",
        "jquery",
        "aurelia-authentication",
        "aurelia-configuration",
        "sweetalert",
        "toastr"
      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": false,
        "rev": false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Served directory**

```
|- dist/
|-- app-build.js
|-- aurelia.js
|- jspm_packages/
|-- github/
|--- ...
|-- npm/
|--- ...
|-- system.js
|-- system-csp-production.js
|-- system-polyfills.js
|- config.js
|- index.html
```

**Body of `index.html`**

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
        <script src="jspm_packages/npm/bluebird@3.4.1/js/browser/bluebird.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
        <script src="config.js"></script>
        <script>
            console.log('test');
            System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper')
                .then(function() {
                    console.log('then');
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('catch', error);
                })
                .finally(function() {
                    console.log('finally');
                });
        </script>
    </body>
```

The only console output from the above is `test`. `bluebird.min.js` and `system.js` requests succeed, as does the `aurelia.js` bundle request. The only odd thing i can see (other than the blank page) is that the `app-build.js` is never requested.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The aurelia bundler hasn't been updated in a while, as the maintainer had some personal and family issues that took him off the project for a while. I'm happy to say that the maintainer has rejoined the Aurelia team, so hopefully any issues that are caused by changes to SystemJS Builder should be resolved soon.

Comment: I had the same issue some days ago and if I remember correctly it was due to an error of mine in one of my callback functions which did not pop the error up to the top to be displayed (for some reason). I would suggest, if you can, to attach the js debugger to a very initial point (maybe in the main.js) to see if you get that far and then step further until it breaks or "vanishes". Your config looks good to me.